Есть ли способы изменить конкретный цвет на экране монитора на другой? (что-то, наподобие "Инверсия цветов" в Windows)
хотел бы узнать, как изменить конкретный цвет на другой цвет (в HEX или RGB) для экрана монитора (чтобы цвет менялся, как в приложениях, играх, так и в самой Windows).
В Windows есть функция "Инверсия цветов", значит предполагаю, что это возможно).
Есть ли подобные программы? Или может быть можно создать свою?
Например черный становиться не таким черным на экране монитора:
#000000 -> #202020
RGB(0,0,0) -> RGB(32,32,32)
В общем с возможностью указать определенный цвет и указать на какой цвет его надо изменить.

По идее в windows есть средства для задания своего LUT.

Как это сделать?)
